# SVG serialization

Tags: json, svg, raphael, simplejson

I have RaphaelJS based canvas, where user can do some work.  I need to do 2 things:

1. Save users work into database
2. Rastersize SVG (I use Apache Batik for that task)

For 1 https://github.com/jspies/raphael.serialize dumps Raphael's canvas to json, then jQuery.getJSON() to send it to the backend, where I need to convert it back to SVG to feed into Batik.

Does this flow seem reasonable?  SVG -> JSON -> SVG conversion seems a bit overhead, is there a better way to do this?

Backend runs python/django.  I use standard json package for JSON -> SVG, but sometimes it fails with syntax errors in the incoming json (mainly in font style properties).  Did anyone face these issues?

What's the best way to store this data in the database? Just as a string?

Comment: How scalable does this app need to be? You might be fine to store the svg text as a big string. But if you have to query on that, or if you are planning on tons of traffic maybe that isn't a good idea.

Comment: At this point of time it doesn't seem that this data will be queried a lot.  Another alternative I see is to store it in text file.

Comment: I refactored raphael.serialize quite a bit to make it work with Raphael 2.0 and handle all elements and transformations: https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raphael.Export saves elements to SVG in any browser that Raphaël supports:

https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.Export

I've used it to save Raphaël drawings as PNGs server-side using Batik.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get a handle on the root `<svg>` element from Raphael then you can convert this to the raw XML source (on the client) and just send that:

```
var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
```

Comment: The thing is that for older browsers there's no <svg>

Comment: @AlexKreimer ...then Raphael does not work, right? Unless you're talking about cases of IE with Raphael running VML as the display layer.